# Laravel 5 action after successful login

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I am wanting to use the built-in scaffolding for Auth and Login, but once a user logs in successfully I want to record that in a database table. I cannot find the right place to put the code. The postLogin() function runs prior to authentication so doesn't seem right to me. I also want to do the same when they log out. Any suggestions?

Comment: If anyone is interested in the answer it can be found here: http://laravel.io/forum/08-27-2015-laravel-5-action-after-successful-login

Comment: check my question here, It may have answer for your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616739/make-an-action-after-login